# With last update to MacOS 10.15 Pulse Secure VPN stopped working

Tags: permission, vpn

With last update to MacOS 10.15 Pulse Secure VPN stopped working. I suspect this is related to the update because several applications needed rights and permissions granted immediately afterwards. iTerm2 f.x. suddenly wouldn't let me list the content of the Download folder and required full disk access rights in "Privacy & Permissions". But so far I didn't find a corresponding permission for this case and the firewall is actually switched off.

[image: Unable to communicate with the server. (Error:1110)]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Pulse-Secure-Login-with-MacOS-Catalina-fail/td-p/41330) thread on pulse secure community forum this **should be resolved by 9.1R3**.

It seems that this update has already started to roll out.

Edit: Just tested 9.1.3 (1313) and it works on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: How do I lay hands on this mysterious 9.1.3 release? https://www.pulsesecure.net/trynow/client-download/ yields a mail leading me to 9.0.4 which I just installed but doesn't solve the issue. Also I get a different error message than the one mentioned in the thread you link: "Unable to communicate with the server. (Error:1110)". Should have put that in the question - will add it.

Comment: I guess you should wait for your company to release the update but if you don't want to wait you can find it [here](https://www.fau.edu/security/vpn/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Installed it but same error. I suspect this is a different problem and indeed related to permissions on my mac. As described in my question I had to reassign permissions for several applications after the update. But for PulseSecure I so far didn't find the right one. The error description also says that the server cannot be reached - but it can - I can curl it. So, I suppose PS is kept from establishing a connection.

Comment: I found a download version of 9.1.3 (9.1R3) [at Osnabrueck University](https://www.rz.uni-osnabrueck.de/Dienste/VPN/index.htm) on OSX section. Still need to test on Catalina, but seems to work on Mojave so looks real.

Answer (score 1):

Pulse Secure is qualifying MacOS Catalina with the current beta release. You have to update it to the latest one.

**Pulse official site also confirmed [this](https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB44202) :**

- Can customers try Pulse Secure products on macOS Catalina?

  Yes. Pulse Secure encourages customers to try the MacOS Catalina with the latest PDC clients of 9.0 and 9.1

Comment: Installed 9.0.4 - problem prevails.

Comment: https://www.primeshare.net/share/82ENRqrqQu1RUJSwvGnKPw==p?dn=1